# Exchange of information between two Web Applications

Tags: java, jsp

I have two Web applications. Webapplication1(java/jsp based) shall send an ID to Webapplication2 (asp based) based on that it would generate a report and that report would be back passed to webapplication1. In webapplication1 we need to view the report.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this? Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by creating a simple web service, using [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).
The **REST** variant is quite simple: the second web application could have a servlet which accepts the request (HTTP GET with parameter, or POST with multipart form data, JSON, or XML), processes it and sends back the response (report as binary data, just like a file download).